# java.text.ParseException: Minute and Second values must be between 0 and 59

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

i scheduling a cron using below code cron expression coming is "0 0 0 * * ?"

```
        CronTriggerImpl trigger = new CronTriggerImpl();
        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = null;
        trigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING);
        trigger.setName(triggerName);
        trigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
```

but it throwing below error at `trigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);` even though i gave right cron

```
java.text.ParseException: Minute and Second values must be between 0 and 59
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.addToSet(CronExpression.java:963) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.checkNext(CronExpression.java:839) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.storeExpressionVals(CronExpression.java:703) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:487) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.<init>(CronExpression.java:276) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl.setCronExpression(CronTriggerImpl.java:347) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at framework
    at framework
    at framework
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) [spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy660.addPartner(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
```

please help me
i stuck at this. is any thing i am missing
even i am giving proper cron getting error

Answer (score -1):

Vey strange. it works for me. I am using Quartz 2.3. May be you can try upgrading.
And use a trigger builder.

```
TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                             .forJob(jobDetail)
                             .withIdentity("my-cron-trigger")
                             .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 0 * * ?"))
                             .build();
```